# Three.js: outline occluded object

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a 3rd person game built on Three.js where the user has free orbital control of the camera.

To enhance player experience, I'd like to use an outline on the active character that the user is controlling (there can be more characters in the scene), but only show the outline when (a part) of the player model is occluded/behind something.

Example:
[image: outline stencil]

The effect I want to create is shown on the far right (Stencil: 1), but instead of an opaque effect, I just want the outline as shown on the other models. There should be no outline on the visible parts of the player character, but only when the character is either partially behind another object or completely.

Now, the outline effect itself isn't really a problem. There are more than enough resources/examples/tutorials/whatnot about that. The part where I'm stuck is how to combine something like this with the occluding part. There is also the part about performance. If at all possible, I would *really* like to avoid rendering my entire scene multiple times for performance reasons.

Thanks in advance!

Using threejs R88 / 89-dev.

Comment: Where is this image from, looks interesting, i'd like to learn more about whats going on in it.

Comment: It's from this one, @pailhead : http://www.tomlooman.com/multi-color-outline-post-process-in-unreal-engine-4/